# How cloudant client can connect to shared database?

Tags: java, cloudant

I have used cloudant client to connect database with this code as:

```
public void setConfig(){
        this.client=new CloudantClient(this.username, this.username, this.password);
        this.database=this.client.database(this.dbName, true);
}
```

It runs well in my own data in IBM cloudant.

I want to use cloudant client to connect to shared data. For instance, other account named "user1" shared a database "user1db" for me with full permission. When I declare `this.dbName="user1/user1db or this.dbName="shared/user1/user1db ";`. It doesn't work.

So how can I connect cloudant client to shared database.

Comment: Will `shared/user1db` work?

Comment: And I think `CloudantClient` should be init with `shared,username,password`

Comment: yeah, CloudantClient already set with init user and password. `shared/user1db` still doesn't work.

Comment: I mean instead of `new CloudantClient(this.username, this.username, this.password);` it should be `new CloudantClient(shared, this.username, this.password);`

Comment: I don't user java client. But when you need to access shared databased in REST api. The URL would be `https://user:pass@shared.cloudant.com/user1db`. So the initialize may need shared. And maybe dbname might be used just `user1db `

Comment: I tried all that ways by setting init CloudantClien and database, unfortunately it still does not work. The system shows "Unknown source" as `at org.lightcouch.CouchDbClientBase.validate(Unknown Source)
at org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient$3.process(Unknown Source)`

Comment: first you should use `new CloudantClient(shared, this.username, this.password);` Then call `client.getAllDbs()` to check

Comment: Can you upgrade you `CloudantClient` to the latest version (2.5.1)  and see if that produces a better error when passing `shared` as the account name to the builder?

Comment: Do you have CORS enabled on your Cloudant account?: https://cloudant.com/blog/shared-databases-faq/ I suspect that could add to the problem.

Comment: @Thaina client.getAllDbs only returns my own databases. It does't not return shared data.

Comment: @brobes It still does not work with enabled CORS.

Comment: @rhyshort I tried with 2.51, but it still does not work.

Comment: File a ticket with Cloudant support, they should be able to investigate further.